# UI Example for selecting multi value

Tags: jsf, user-interface, multivalue

In my form  there is text box that allow multi value input with a delimiter

example "AU,RU,SG,US"

user can add in multi value..

May I know if there is anywhere site that shows UI input example for such data?

currently we are using a popup bean with 2 list box, one list box contains all the available data, another for selection.

I am wondering if there are other better approach.

Added explanation: There is a textbox with a button  to click.

and when a user click the button, a popup will appear.

The popup will have 2 list. List one shows all the available values to choose from and user can move the another list box.

The user will click update button once he/she finish his selection and it will update the text field with the selected data.

My question is what other ways of UI presentation are there available for multi-value selections. In future the values might be display in a Tree and user have to select some of the nodes.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain further what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `richfaces`, probably you can use [list-shuttle](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/listShuttle.jsf?c=listShuttle&tab=usage) or various other rich selects available.

Coming up to UI perspective it is more soothy and apt to selection as user can view the options (s)he has selected all at a time.

Another ways or options that can be is have a `checkbox in combo` and let user select multiple checks from the combo selection. Example [here](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/). Which is more convincing I believe if you wish to have a `compact and friendly UI`.

Or if you have limited number of options then simply place `checkboxs` against number of options to select.

Comment: yup we are using custom list-shuttle kind of component. I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: @seesee - did you check combo sample?